# placing string from one view controller to the delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

having issues getting a value from a NSString in my view controller to my delegate. The issue is the userId string. it comes back with an error in the delegate

error: accessing unknown 'userId' class method

view controller snippet ( profileViewController.m )

```
  -(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:0];
    self.userId = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"id"]];

    NSLog(@"DONE PARSING DOCUMENT");
    NSLog(self.userId);

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Profile";
    interestingTags = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: INTERESTING_TAG_NAMES];
    self.userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

delegate

```
    #import "profileViewController.h"

@implementation experimentAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize rootController;

    -(void)goingOffline
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data]; 

    NSString *userID = profileViewController.userId;

    NSString *userString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"id=%@", userID];

    //NSLog(nameString);
    //NSLog(numberString);

    [data appendData:[userString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.net/test.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profileViewController` is your class. To access `userId` directly, it should be defined as,

```
+ (NSString *) userId;
```

and not,

```
- (NSString *) userId; // (or)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * userId;
```

**Edit**

Since `profileViewController` is one of the view controllers in the tab bar controller instance `rootController`, you can try getting the `profileViewController` instance like this,

```
profileViewController * theController;
NSArray * viewControllers = rootController.viewControllers;
for ( UIViewController * viewController in viewControllers ) {
    if ( [viewController isMemberOfClass:[profileViewController class]] ) {
        theController = viewController;
    }
}

NSString * userID = theController.userId;
```

Comment: it comes back null now when placing userID in a NSLog using profileViewController *controller = [[profileViewController alloc] init]; NSString *userID = controller.userId;

Comment: Yeah but that's because you haven't set it. Is `rootController` an instance of `profileViewController`?

Comment: rootController is a tab bar controller which then loads the profileViewController then the profileViewController sets the userId, I am then trying to get the userId back to the delegate so when i close the application, it sends the userId to a server to tell the sever that user has closed the application.

Comment: warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct UIViewController *', expected 'struct profileViewController *'

Comment: Replace `theController = viewController;` with `theController = (profileViewController *)viewController;` but did you get a log?

Comment: @Mintuz Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it instance variable.
If you have `-(NSString *)` it can only be accessed within that file even if your importing it in another file.  If you use `+(NSString *)` you will not get that error anymore.  The same works for voids `+(void)`. Good Luck